# PySpark TimestampType() providing wrong conversion: ValueError: year 52129 is out of range

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting a collection with Timestamp value in PySpark from MongoDB through Kafka. In MongoDB, the schema is as following:

```
"Timestamp": {
        "$date": "2020-02-28T11:24:28.810Z"
    }
```

In PySpark I am using the following schema:

```
StructType([...
         StructField("Timestamp",StructType([StructField("$date",TimestampType(),True)]), True), \
         ...
```

I am using from_json() to parse the json-string:

```
data_stream_clean = data_stream_after \
                .select(from_json(col("json_string"), self.schema) \
                .alias("detail")) \
                .select("detail.*") \
                .withColumn("Timestamp", col("Timestamp").getField("$date"))
```

Then I am creating a tempView to access the columns, which shows:

```
+---+--------------------+
| Id|           Timestamp|
+---+--------------------+
|231|52129-10-04 10:00...
```

which is wrong conversion of 2020-02-28T11:24:28.810Z. I cannot tranform this into a df which shows the following error:

```
ValueError: year 52129 is out of range
```

I have also used unix_timestamp(), which shows the correct conversion i.e. 1582889068810 but in int datatype. However I would like to have my data in timestamp.

Comment: Why does your dataframe schema defines Timestamp as array of timestamps?

Comment: The schema contains other fielsd too.

Answer (score 1):

I tried reading the your sample input as josn, it is working well in scala.
Can you tell how are you loading the dataframe or the scenario?

## Code

```scala
  val spark = sqlContext.sparkSession
    val implicits = spark.implicits
    import implicits._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection

    val data =
      """
        |{
        |   "Timestamp": {
        |       "$date": "2020-02-28T11:24:28.810Z"
        |   }
        |}
      """.stripMargin
    val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("Timestamp",StructType(Array(StructField("$date", DataTypes.TimestampType))))))


    val ds = spark.read
      .schema(schema)
      .json(Seq(data).toDS())

    ds.show(false)
    ds.printSchema()
```

Result-

```
+------------------------+
|Timestamp               |
+------------------------+
|[2020-02-28 16:54:28.81]|
+------------------------+

root
 |-- Timestamp: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- $date: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Even I tried it reading as `string` and then casted the column to `Timestamp`, but the result is same-

```
 val data =
      """
        |{
        |   "Timestamp": {
        |       "$date": "2020-02-28T11:24:28.810Z"
        |   }
        |}
      """.stripMargin
    val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("Timestamp",StructType(Array(StructField("$date", DataTypes.StringType))))))


    val ds = spark.read
      .schema(schema)
      .json(Seq(data).toDS())

    ds.show(false)
    ds.printSchema()

    ds.select(col("Timestamp.$date").cast(DataTypes.TimestampType)).show(false)
```

Result:

```
+--------------------------+
|Timestamp                 |
+--------------------------+
|[2020-02-28T11:24:28.810Z]|
+--------------------------+

root
 |-- Timestamp: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- $date: string (nullable = true)

+----------------------+
|$date                 |
+----------------------+
|2020-02-28 16:54:28.81|
+----------------------+
```

If you are loading the data using `DataFrameReader` then you can change the format using below option -

```
.option("timestampFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZ")
```

### from_json

Loading data from from_json worked well for me

```
 val df = Seq(data).toDF("json_string")
      .select(from_json(col("json_string"), schema).alias("detail"))
      .select("detail.*")
    .withColumn("Timestamp", col("Timestamp").getField("$date"))
df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

+------------------------+
|Timestamp               |
+------------------------+
|2020-02-28T11:24:28.810Z|
+------------------------+

root
 |-- Timestamp: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Hi, I am using from_json with the scheme to parse the json. I have updated the question.

Comment: even from_json worked well. please see my edited reply

Comment: I am not sure whats  going on. I used unix_timestamp to realize the timestamp in ms and then divided it by 1000 to realize my application.